# TodoMVC with ember, id does not increment

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, todomvc

I am following the getting started guide from emberjs, and am at the point where I can add todos. My problem is though that when I add a todo it has an id value of null - is there a practical way to auto increment this?

```
var TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
actions: {
    createTodo: function() {
        var title = this.get('newTitle');
        if (!title.trim()) {
            return;
        }

        var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
            title: title,
            isCompleted: false
        });

        this.set('newTitle', '');

        todo.save();
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `this.store.createRecord()` you have an "option" to have an `id` autogenerated (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L313)) Ultimately though, that responsibility is delegated to an `adapter`. If your adapter has `generateIdForRecord()` method - this will be used to create an id. So, for example, `FixtureAdapter` implements this method as follows (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L128)):

```
generateIdForRecord: function(store) {
  return "fixture-" + counter++;
}
```

ember-data uses `RestAdapter` by default (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L224)), so you would need to add the method for the `id` to be generated on the client...